# How to change the vertical align of text in a UILabel (iOS8)

Tags: ios, swift, label, text-alignment

I'm making an app in which I need the text in a very large UILabel to appear at the bottom of the bounds of the label. Is there anyway to do this?

Through code or storyboards is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With auto layout this is quite easy to do.

1. Put the label into a container `UIView`.
2. Set the constraints so it touches the sides and is fixed to the bottom.
3. Leave the height variable, based on the content.

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3 here's a top align

```
@objc(TopAlignLabel)
class TopAlignLabel: UILabel {

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        var targetRect = textRect(forBounds: rect, limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines)
        targetRect.origin.y = 0
        super.drawText(in: targetRect)
    }
}
```

for bottom align use `rect.size.height - targetRect.size.height` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If subclassing is suitable for you, you can subclass UILabel and override the |drawTextInRect:| method to adjust the drawing area(CGRect) before actually drawing the text

```objc
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGRect targetRect = [self textRectForBounds:rect limitedToNumberOfLines:self.numberOfLines];
    targetRect.origin.y = rect.size.height - targetRect.size.height;
    [super drawTextInRect:targetRect];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Officially, we don't have api to change the vertical align of a UILabel's text. However, we can adjust the frame of your UILabel (as described in [this post](http://answersfordevelopers.blogspot.fr/2014/08/ios-how-to-vertically-align-text-within.html)), or we can use some private API [like this](https://github.com/ecentinela/UILabel-VerticalAlignment) (not recommended)